# Como gerar um arquivo de uma lista duplamente encadeada?

Tags: c, arquivo

não consegui de maneira nenhuma fazer com que meu programa salve em arquivo no final.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>


struct stNo {
    int info;
    char nome[50];
    char email[60];
    char celular[11];
    int idade;
    struct stNo *ant,*prox;
};


struct stNo *cria_no() {
    struct stNo *p;
    if ((p = (struct stNo *) malloc(sizeof(struct stNo))) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else {
        p->prox = NULL;
        return p;
    }
}





void insereLista(struct stNo **list){
    struct stNo *p,*q;
    int n,idade1;
    char name[50],email1[60],celular1[11];
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nDigite o valor do nó:");
    scanf("%i",&n);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nDigite o nome:");
    gets(name);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nDigite o email:");
    gets(email1);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nDigite o celular:");
    gets(celular1);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nDigite o valor da idade:");
    scanf("%i",&idade1);
    fflush(stdin);
    if(*list==NULL){ //lista vazia
        p = cria_no();
        *list = p;
        p->ant = NULL;
        p->prox = NULL;
        p->info = n;
        p->idade = idade1;
        strcpy(p->nome,name);
        strcpy(p->email,email1);
        strcpy(p->celular,celular1);
        
    }else{
        p=*list;
        while(p->prox!=NULL)
            p=p->prox;
            q = cria_no();
            p->prox = q;
            q->prox = NULL;
            q->ant = p;
            q->info = n;
            q->idade = idade1;
            strcpy(q->nome,name);
            strcpy(q->email,email1);
            strcpy(q->celular,celular1);
        };
};

void mostraLista(struct stNo **list){
    struct stNo *p;
    if(*list!=NULL){
        p=*list;
        while(p->prox!=NULL){
            printf(" %i->",p->info);
            printf(" %s->",p->nome);
            p = p->prox;
        };
        printf(" %i->",p->info);
        printf(" %s",p->nome);
    }
    else printf("\nLista Vazia");
};

void visualizarLista(struct stNo **list){
    struct stNo *p;
    int n;
    char compNome[50];
    printf("\nDigite o nome: ");
     fflush(stdin);
    gets(compNome);
    if(*list!=NULL){
        p=*list;
        while(p->prox!=NULL && strcmp(compNome,p->nome) !=0 ){
            p = p->prox;
        };
        if(strcmp(compNome,p->nome)==0){
            printf("\nCódigo: %d",p->info);
            printf("\nNome: %s",p->nome);
            printf("\nEmail: %d",p->email);
            printf("\nCelular: %s",p->celular);
            printf("\nIdade: %d",p->idade);
        };
    }
    else printf("\nLista Vazia");
};

void alterarLista(struct stNo **list){
    struct stNo *p;
    int n,idade1;
    char name[50],email1[60],celular1[11];
    char compNome[50];
    printf("\nDigite o nome que sera alterado: ");
     fflush(stdin);
    gets(compNome);
    if(*list!=NULL){
        p=*list;
        while(p->prox!=NULL && strcmp(compNome,p->nome) !=0 ){
            p = p->prox;
        };
        if(strcmp(compNome,p->nome)==0){
            
    printf("\nDigite o novo valor do nó:");
    scanf("%i",&n);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nDigite o novo nome:");
    gets(name);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nDigite o novo email:");
    gets(email1);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nDigite o novo celular:");
    gets(celular1);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nDigite o novo valor da idade:");
    scanf("%i",&idade1);
    fflush(stdin);
            p->info = n;
            p->idade = idade1;
            strcpy(p->nome,name);
            strcpy(p->email,email1);
            strcpy(p->celular,celular1);
            
            printf("\nNovos dados do usuario: ");
            printf("\nCódigo: %d",p->info);
            printf("\nNome: %s",p->nome);
            printf("\nEmail: %d",p->email);
            printf("\nCelular: %s",p->celular);
            printf("\nIdade: %d",p->idade); 
    
        };
    }
    else printf("\nLista Vazia");
};

void excluirQualquer(struct stNo **list){
    
    struct stNo *p;
    char compNome[50];
    p = *list;
    if(*list==NULL){
        printf("\nLista Vazia");
    }else{
    
    
    printf("\nDigite o nome: ");
     fflush(stdin);
    gets(compNome);
    if(*list!=NULL) //lista vazia
    p = *list;
    while(p->prox!=NULL && strcmp(compNome,p->nome) !=0){
        p=p->prox;
    }     
         
         if(p->ant == NULL){
            *list = p->prox;
         }else{
            p->ant->prox = p->prox;      
         }
            
         if(p->prox != NULL)
         p->prox->ant = p->ant;
         free(p);
         printf("\nExcluido com sucesso. ");        
}
};





main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    struct stNo *lista;
    int menu;
    lista = NULL; // inicializando a lista vazia

    do{
        system("cls");
        printf("\n");
        mostraLista(&lista);
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("[1-Inserir] ");
        printf("[2-Visualizar] ");
        printf("[3-Alterar] ");
        printf("[4-Excluir] ");
        printf("[5-Sair] ");
        printf("Opção:");
        scanf("%i",&menu);
        switch(menu){
            case 1 :    insereLista(&lista);
                        break;          
            case 2 :    visualizarLista(&lista);
                        break;
            case 3 :    alterarLista(&lista);
                        break;  
            case 4 :    excluirQualquer(&lista);
                        break;                  
            case 5 :    printf("\nSaindo...");
                        break;
            default:    printf("\nCódigo Inválido");
        }
        printf("\n");system("pause");
        }while(menu!=5);
}
```

Comment: você nem ao menos tentou implementar a lógica de salvar. Dica: percorre a lista pra saber quantos elementos tem, salva a quantidade de elementos no inicio do arquivo pra faciliar a leitura quando for carregar os dados numa execução futura do programa.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, isso ocorre porque todo o seu programa não está usando nenhum método de salvamento de arquivo :) Se quiser salvar sua lista, você pode usar a variável do tipo FILE* e, depois disso, usar as funções fwrite e fread para escrever e ler o arquivo, respectivamente. Por fim, você não pode esquecer de colocar fclose(arquivo_var); para salvar o documento. Segue um exemplo:

FILE* arquivo_var = fopen('Nome do seu arquivo', "w"); // esse w significa 'write' e cria um arquivo caso esse ainda não exista
fwrite(q->nome , strlen(q->nome) , sizeof(q->nome) , arquivo_var);
fclose(arquivo_var);

Comment: sim essa parte eu entendi, mas não estou conseguindo aplicar, ou transformar isso em uma função.